# Javascript Recursion Tree Building

Tags: javascript, algorithm, tree

I am having an issue building a tree from a flat array. I am building a category -> subcategory tree in which the parent has subcategories as an array.

Here is what the flat array would look like:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "parent_id": 1
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "parent_id": 1
  },
  {
    "id": 42,
    "parent_id": 5
  },
  {
    "id": 67,
    "parent_id": 5
  }
]
```

And this is what I need the result to look:

```
[
  {
    "id":1,
    "subcategories":[
      {
        "id":2,
        "parent_id":1
      },
      {
        "id":3,
        "parent_id":1
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id":5,
    "subcategories":[
      {
        "id":42,
        "parent_id":5
      },
      {
        "id":67,
        "parent_id":5
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I have tried to do this recursively by recursively searching for children and attaching it as an array and continuing to do so until I hit the bottom of the barrel but I am getting a cyclic structure. It appears that the parent_id in traverse is always the id of the parent... any ideas:

```
tree(passingInFlatObjectHere);

function topLevel (data) {
  let blob = [];
  data.forEach((each) => {
    if (!each.parent_id) {
      blob.push(each);
    }
  });
  return blob;
}

function tree (data) {
  let blob = topLevel(data).map(function (each) {
    each.subcategories = traverse(data, each.id);
    return each;
  });
  return blob;
}

function traverse (data, parent_id) {
  let blob = [];
  if (!parent_id) {
    return blob;
  }
  data.forEach((each) => {
    if (each.id === parent_id) {
      each.subcategories = traverse(data, each.id);
      blob.push(each);
    }
  });
  return blob;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don’t just want to help you fix your problem but would also like to help you take full advantage of ES6

First of all your `topLevel` function can be rewritten to this:

```
function topLevel(data) {
  return data.filter(node => !node.parent_id);
}
```

Neat isn’t it? I also would recommend slightly changing `tree` for consistency but that’s of course just stylistic.

```
function tree(data) {
  return topLevel(data).map(each => {
    each.subcategories = traverse(data, each.id);
    return each;
  });
}
```

No logic issues so far. `traverse`, however, contains one, when you check `each.id === parent_id`. Like this, the functions searches for the node whose id is `parent_id`. Obviously a mistake. You wanted `each.parent_id === parent_id`.

Your issue is solved now. Stop reading if I bother you. But you could also take advantage of `filter` here and remove that slightly superfluous early exit and rewrite your function to:

```
function traverse(data, parentId) {
  const children = data.filter(each => each.parent_id === parentId);
  children.forEach(child => {
    child.subcategories = traverse(data, child.id);
  });
  return children;
}
```

Comment: Wow thanks for the help and showing me all the nice new sugar in ES6.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need install **lodash** with below command with npm:

```
npm i lodash
```

Second, you must import _ from lodash

```
import _ from "lodash";
```

Finally, run this function:

```
export const recursive_lists = (data) => {
  const grouped = _.groupBy(data, (item) => item. parent_id);

  function childrenOf(parent_id) {
    return (grouped[parent_id] || []).map((item) => ({
      id: item.id,
      child: childrenOf(item.id),
    }));
  }

  return childrenOf(null);
};
```

**or**

First:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.20/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Second:

```
function recursive_lists(data) {
  const grouped = _.groupBy(data, (item) => item.parent_id);

  function childrenOf(parent_id) {
    return (grouped[parent_id] || []).map((item) => ({
      id: item.id,
      child: childrenOf(item.id),
    }));
  }

  return childrenOf(null);
};
```